# Electrode Server Plugin (with Express)

Tags: express, walmart-electrode

It appears that [Electode's server plugin mechanism](https://docs.electrode.io/chapter1/intermediate/build-a-server-plugin.html) only works with Hapi. Can anyone confirm that?